# It is necessary that A such that B is sufficient.

Tags: logic

The task is to find an expression/value for A and B (in either mathematic or natural language) that causes the above statement to be true. I find this question very ambiguous as I do not understand the final few words, 'such that B is sufficient.' What is B supposed to be sufficient for?

I would normally assume that the question is asking what B could be to make it sufficient for A, but the previous question asks quite a similar thing and makes it clear that B is meant to be sufficient for A, so I can only assume that they would always include this information in the question if it were relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary that there be a question posted on Math StackExchange such that giving the answer I'm writing right now is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still do not understand how this satisfies the question (please note that this is an issue with my understanding rather than your answer). What is the relevance of B being 'sufficient,' and what is it sufficient to?

Comment: Honestly I also think "It is necessary that A such that B is sufficient" sounds strange... I'm not sure it's a well thought out exercise.

Comment: Ok - thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not really grammatical if A and B are supposed to be the same of thing. You can't say "It's necessary that 1+1=2 such that 2+2=4"... it doesn't parse into a sentence.